# How to organize code (component) sharing in multiple vue applications WITHOUT a monorepo

Tags: vue.js, npm, yarnpkg, package-managers, code-reuse

We're planning three similar vue projects. We already know that we will be able to reuse a lot of code (especially vue SFCs and simple js helper functions) in all of them and we're looking for a proper way to share the code between them.

Unfortunately the scope of the projects is rather different and a monorepo is ***not*** an option due to its limitations in read / write permission and visibility management. Therefore we're planning to handle the reusable parts as separate repos (and most likely private npm packages) which seems to be a straightforward approach. **However, the question is: How can we create a convenient setup in which we are able to work on the shared components from within the scope of one of the parent projects?**

Project A [project-repo-a]

- project-specific stuff for A
- private package A [package-repo-a] (conveniently editable from within project A)
- private package B [package-repo-b] (conveniently editable from within project A)

Project B [project-repo-b]

- project-specific stuff for B
- private package B [package-repo-b] (conveniently editable from within project B)
- private package C [package-repo-c] (conveniently editable from within project B)

In our PHP projects, there is a simple solution, we just require the reusable parts via composer with the prefer-source option which provides the full git repository which can be worked on right from within the parent application. However, as far as we understand there is no prefer-source thing in npm or yarn. So how can we achieve the desired setup? (Or are we overlooking a major downside of this setup in general?)

**We already looked into / considered the following (without finding a suitable approach):**

- ***yarn / npm link:*** We understood, that we could use linking in general, but this seems to be a very inconvenient approach while constantly developing the shared components (and always having to publish them to reflect the latest changes).
- ***yarn workspaces / lerna:*** Seem to be closest to what we want, however they seem to be (or are explicitly) designed for a monorepo approach. In the end they don't to provide a solution for actually getting the git source of a package (in a separate repo) into the parent project (since there is no --prefer-source thing) - do they?
- ***using composer additionally:*** Just pulling the git sources down with composer and creating yarn workspaces from the composer vendor folder. However, this is obviously a hacky way and sounds quite error prone concerning the whole dependency management
- ***using a yarn post-install script*** to pull down the git source of the required private packages, but as the composer way, this seems to be rather unpredictable in terms of module resolution, dependency management and so on.
- ***using git submodules and yarn workspaces:*** Could be a solution. To be honest we're just completely unexperienced with git submodules and at a first glance it didn't look very intuitive. If there is no other way, we'll anyways consider to use this approach.

To be clear about this: We're **not** asking the taste question if one or the other of those approaches would be "best". We're feeling like none of them is the right one. The question is: Are we overlooking a technically clean and proven approach to our scenario, using npm, yarn or another package manager / dependency management solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Git X-Modules](https://gitmodules.com) is a tool designed to do exactly what you were asking about. Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdoQNQ5Akxw) that explains it. However, it's very new and therefore can't be really considered "proven" :-)
Yet, if you consider trying it, we would love to hear your feedback!

(As you may guess from the previous sentence, I am a part of the development team.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, sounds interesting! However, I'm not sure if or how this would solve our problem, since we're looking for a solution that will make the packages editable **while** taking care of the dependency management at the same time. So do I understand you correctly, that, with regard to our scenario, you are proposing to use Git X-Modules together with yarn workspaces? Could you elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: And one more question about how your project woks: When using Git X-Modules, are the local package repositories actually "real" repositories, so that, for example, the IDE will recognise them as separate VCS sources?

Comment: @btl-sw 

- Git X-Modules maintain a two-way synchronization between the parent and the module repositories. You can change the code from either side, and the changes will be automatically applied to the other.
- The parent repository is just a regular repository, like any other, so you may use in with any Git client or IDE. Git X-Modules work on the server.

Comment: In your example, when you have Package B included as a directory in Project A, a directory in Project B and also existing in a separate repository:
- You push your changes to Project A (that may contain specific project A stuff, and also some changes to Package B - in one push). 
- Then Git X-Modules in Project A selects the changes that affect Package B, and synchs them with the Package B's own repository. 
- In about a minute (depends on the polling interval) Git X-Modules in Project B pulls these changes to Project B repository.

Comment: I am not sure how this works with yarn workspaces - I have no experience with it. But I will ask my colleague who has.

Comment: X-Modules with Yarn workspaces works similarly to Git submodules: you put each module into a separate repository and then tie all together with a special "parent.git" repository where each moduleA.git, moduleB.git, ... is mounted into packages/moduleA, packages/moduleB, ... of parent.git. So you can open-source moduleA.git while keeping moduleB.git and parent.git private. X-Modules synchronizes each moduleX.git with packages/moduleX on the server side, while Git submodules - on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have already figured this out but have you looked into https://bit.dev/ ?
I'm currently considering it for a similar task to yours and it looks like it could do the job. Here's an article explaining how to use it https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-easily-share-vue-components-between-applications-1d30a1ad4e4d

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30592254)